Arrow passing through rings?
The scene was something like this guy was not in the town for a while, he comes back in disguise or so and they have a challenge to pass the arrow in the middle of rings it was like a bar and he does it.
Setup looks like the movie Braveheart or Robin Hood. Movie is not animated. I tried looking for that scene here, couldn't find it. Movie would be around late 90s early 2000 if I can guess. 
Anyone knows of a movie like that?

You're describing a scene from Homer's Odyssey which had many, many adaptations and parodies etc., so take your pick. More details (like year of release, color\B&W, country of origin, action\animated and possible actors) will help narrow it down.

setup looks like the movie braveheart or robin hood.. Movie not animation... I tried looking for that scene in the above movies couldn't find it. Movie would be around late 90s early 2000 if I can guess.

@Kelly Welcome to Movies & TV. It seems you are the original asker. If that's the case, you might want to merge your account with the one you asked the question with in order for you to make the most out of the site, including being able to edit your information into the question and properly react to any possible answers. For more information how the site works, you might want to take a look at the [tour] or the [help].

@NapoleonWilson yes it is but I used my phone and I guess I had an account before or so.. I did what you ask thank you :)

Hi guys, I love your knowledge of movies it's very interesting and very comprehensive answers I love that.. I didn't watch the movie that was supplied here the movie I'm talking about would be a bit more famous like Troy or similar. As far as I remember the guy was the hero of the movie and he was a bit of a famous actor it's all really vague in my mind I can't remember more.

Maybe you are thinking of this rendition of the Odyssey. It starred Armand Assante as Odysseus and Eric Roberts as Eurymachus. This is the made for TV version which came out in 1997. There is the scene (as is not complete without it) where Odysseus first strings the bow then shoots the arrow through the rings.
(NOTE: I believe this video is a kluge of two movies, but I am unsure)


 

That's the one I'm thinking of too. The '97 version is the "straight" rendition I remember most clearly, since b/c of when it came out, it's one I watched in school when we studied Greek mythology.

Yeah, but didn't suggest it because it's in that list the OP says they went over. But maybe they just missed it, who knows.

@Walt ... Am I missing something? I don't see him mentioning an Odyssey movie in his question or comments. You mentioned Odyssey in your comment, but I was thinking of this before I read that. (Though going back I did miss the link in the question).

Look closer. ;) I supplied a Wiki link of Odyssey adaptations in the first comment. He said he went over them in the 2nd comment, so I added it into the question. This one is in that list, but again, maybe the OP missed it or skipped it because it's a miniseries.

@Walt ... yes, missed the link. Darn things are so light in the new style, it blends in with the text very well.

I think there's enough contrast (maybe not on smartphones), though we can always make them bold. But I think we're getting sidetracked and will shortly be admonished for it. :P

Yes, yes we will ... duck.

Well, the more famous film version of the Odyssey is Ulysses (1954) . Ulysses is the Latin name for Odysseus. 
Kirk Douglas played Ulysses, and while that movie is well out of your date range, it contains the classic Archery test (stringing Ulysses' mighty bow and shooting an arrow with it through a row of rings. 




Very interesting I watched the whole scene :) the movie I wanted was a bit famous like a blockbuster kinda thing it wasn't that old and the actor was kinda famous it sticks me like Russell crow or so... Also the scene as I remember it wasn't to save the queen just losers playing in the bar and he walks in and shoots he didn't have to do anything else. But thank you really I love the comments here and enthusiasm of the site =D
